# commandLink actionListener methods on bean passed via ui:param

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I'm using JSF 2 with PrimeFaces, and my facelet has commandLinks (or commandButtons) that calls methods on a bean passed in via ui:param.

My facelet xhtml expects `dialogBean` to be passed as a `ui:param`

```
   <h:panelGroup>

       <p:commandButton
           value="#{msgs.ok}"
           actionListener="#{dialogBean.okClicked}"
           process="#{dialogId}"
           update="#{dialogId}, #{externalIdsToUpdateOnOk}"
           styleClass="dialogBottomBtn"
        />

        <p:commandButton
            value="#{msgs.cancel}"
            actionListener="#{dialogBean.close}"
            process="@this"
            update="#{dialogId}"
            styleClass="dialogBottomBtn"
        />

   </h:panelGroup>
```

The facelet is included like this:

```
<ui:include src="/faces/common/dialogButtons.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="dialogId" value="textBlockQuestionDialog" />
    <ui:param name="dialogBean" value="#{formEditor.textBlockQuestionDialog}" />
    <ui:param name="externalIdsToUpdateOnOk" value=":form:tree, :form:properties, :form:preview" />
</ui:include>
```

It fails with this error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 
   identifier 'dialogBean' resolved to null
```

I've tried replacing `#{dialogBean.close}` with `#{dialogBean['close']}`, `#{dialogBean[action]}` with `action` defined as param, nothing helped.

`dialogBean` *does* get resolved when used with `h:outputText` and similar outputs.  Also, this example works when I replace `actionListener` with `action`.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.  Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.

Double-check that your `dialogBean` object's actionListener methods (`okClicked` etc.) take an `ActionEvent` parameter.

It seems like this parameter is required for beans passed by `ui:param`, but not others.

I suspect what's going on is something like this:

1. check `dialogBean` parameter for method `okClicked(ActionEvent)`
2. if not found, look for bean named `dialogBean` with method `okClicked(ActionEvent)`
3. if not found, look for bean named `dialogBean` with method `okClicked()`

where the no-argument method is only used when the bean name directly matches, not indirectly matches via ui:param reference.